# Why are WSUS shared folders shared out to entire network?

Tags: security, permissions, network-share, wsus, server-message-block

I set up a Server 2012 R2 instance as a WSUS server and went through initial set up. But now, from another computer on LAN, when I type explore to the server via UNC path I see Wsuscontent and WSUSTemp shared out to the whole network. The odd thing is when I look at properties of these folders on the server itself it says the folder is not shared. Yet when I load up Server Manager->File And Storage Services->Shares I see these folders as being shared.

Why are they being shared in this way and why is the shared state not being reflected in properties?

Also, is this a security risk? If so, how would I go about locking this down? What is recommended best practice here?

I appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: How would you think should WSUS share its updates, if not by Windows share? I don't have a 2012R2 + WSUS atm, but in 2008 and 2016 the shares are visible in the properties, but read only for "everyone", read/write for admins and the network service, etc. Yre you sure the share isn't hidden in the properties?